# PredictionIO - Error when trainning kmean clustering

Tags: k-means, training-data, predictionio

I followed the guidance below to train and deploy [KMean clustering](https://templates.prediction.io/sahiliitm/predictionio-MLlibKMeansClusteringTemplate).

But I got error with pio train:

```
      [WARN] [Template$] template.json does not exist. Template metadata will not be available. (This is safe to ignore if you are not working on a template.)
      [INFO] [Runner$] Submission command: /home/lavalamp/PredictionIO/vendors/spark-1.4.1/bin/spark-submit --class io.prediction.workflow.CreateWorkflow --jars file:/home/lavalamp/PredictionIO/MyKmeans/target/scala-2.10/template-scala-parallel-vanilla_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,file:/home/lavalamp/PredictionIO/MyKmeans/target/scala-2.10/template-scala-parallel-vanilla-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT-deps.jar --files file:/home/lavalamp/PredictionIO/conf/log4j.properties --driver-class-path /home/lavalamp/PredictionIO/conf file:/home/lavalamp/PredictionIO/lib/pio-assembly-0.9.4.jar --engine-id gYCE4NX4ODPQkryp9Jq9by3OEXxa4fxQ --engine-version b972fa8f340c142fb6dffbebc6d276b3bb32eeda --engine-variant file:/home/lavalamp/PredictionIO/MyKmeans/engine.json --verbosity 0 --json-extractor Both 
      --env PIO_ENV_LOADED=1,PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_NAME=pio_meta,PIO_FS_BASEDIR=/home/lavalamp/.pio_store,PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_MYSQL_URL=jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.73/pio,PIO_HOME=/home/lavalamp/PredictionIO,
      PIO_FS_ENGINESDIR=/home/lavalamp/.pio_store/engines,PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_MYSQL_TYPE=jdbc,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_SOURCE=MYSQL,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_SOURCE=MYSQL,
      PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDATA_NAME=pio_event,PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_MYSQL_USERNAME=root,PIO_FS_TMPDIR=/home/lavalamp/.pio_store/tmp,
      PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_NAME=pio_model,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDATA_SOURCE=MYSQL,
      PIO_CONF_DIR=/home/lavalamp/PredictionIO/conf


      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.biglabs.VanillaEngine$ cannot be cast to io.prediction.controller.EngineFactory

at io.prediction.workflow.WorkflowUtils$.getEngine(WorkflowUtils.scala:69)
at io.prediction.workflow.CreateWorkflow$.liftedTree1$1(CreateWorkflow.scala:193)
at io.prediction.workflow.CreateWorkflow$.main(CreateWorkflow.scala:192)
at io.prediction.workflow.CreateWorkflow.main(CreateWorkflow.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution, https://github.com/singsanj/KMeans-parallel-template

hope this solve your issues.

just dont forget to update the scripts/loadData.py with you newly created app access  key and engine.json with your appId.

if you still have issues.. happy to solve.